# Unexplained wait time in function After in time package (well, package time inside of time package)

Tags: go, time, timer

Learning time.After in golang, I see below from the example

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var c chan int

func handle(int) {}

func main() {
    select {
    case m := <-c:
        handle(m)
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
    }
}
```

So digging into the source code, (I understand what it does, but wanted to see from source code), I went to sleep.go, and see

```
func After(d Duration) <-chan Time {

    return NewTimer(d).C

}
```

And New Timer

```
func NewTimer(d Duration) *Timer {
    c := make(chan Time, 1)
    t := &Timer{
        C: c,
        r: runtimeTimer{
            when: when(d),
            f:    sendTime,
            arg:  c,
        },
    }
    startTimer(&t.r)
    return t

}
```

Which does not lead to anything. startTimer is just function that takes struct

```
func startTimer(*runtimeTimer)
```

and I really am stuck trying to see what makes function After wait x Duration before returning. Can someone please help me explain this for me?

Comment: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/go-timers/. The article is a few years old and implementation details may have changed. I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't lead to anything". [startTimer obviously calls addtimer](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.16/src/runtime/time.go#L212) and so on.

Comment: will check it out. What I meant was I expected to find some code that says wait x interval before returning

Answer (score 0):

If You need to see more about this, just open your [`GOROOT/src/runtime/time.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/time.go) file and look into function `startTimer(t *timer)` at line 208 (my go version is go1.15.6 darwin/amd64). When you open Go runtime package with an IDE, you can go head.